# What file sizes and formats are most appropriate for enlarging and projecting an image onto a large wallspace for painting?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I think my title question says it all. I have hand drawn some designs (A3) that will be projected onto a 9m X 7m brick wall. This design will be painted as a mural.

I'm concerned about the appropriate file size and format to use as I need to retain a clear image to work with.

Comment: You tagged with "Photoshop" so the natural advice is "use Illustrator instead".

Answer (score 2):

Try not to make a mountain out of a molehill.

The resolution of anything you want to project is limited by the resolution of your projector. If your projector uses a resolution of let's say Full HD, 1920x1080 px that is the file size you need. You can not have more than that.

If you need to use more detail, you could project by zones, for example dividing your wall in a 2x2 grid, then you can have an image 4 times bigger (2x2 bigger).

The format is irrelevant. You could leave the design in the application's native format or use a generic one like PNG.

You potentially could need your original design prepared in a vector based program, so you can play with this output files.

Of course, this depends on what are this "Designs" and what is inside them.

This designs should be a guideline, the detail will come hopefully with the skill of the person painting the wall.

Comment: Alternative copy your atwork on a transparency and project it with a overhead projector.